# Laravel form doesn't update values in database instead is delete them

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have form where I can change user role. When I try to change and hit Save button I've got invalid foreach() argument error and previous record in database for this user is deleted completely.

This is my form

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['admin.addper', $user->user_id]]) !!}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="title" class="control-block">Username:</label>
                {{ Form::text('username', $user->username, ['class' => 'form-control', 'disabled']) }}
         </div>
    </div><!-- end col-4/12 -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title" class="control-block">Choose which Role you want to assign to user:</label><br>
                @foreach($roles as $value)
                    {{ Form::checkbox('roles', $value->id, in_array($value->id, $userRole) ? true : false, array('class' => 'name')) }}
                        <strong>{{ $value->display_name }}</strong> 
                        <br/>
                @endforeach
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And this is the controller part

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'roles' => 'required'
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->update($input);
    DB::table('role_user')->where('user_id',$id)->delete();

    foreach ($request->input('roles') as $key => $value) {
        $user->attachRole($value);
    }

    return redirect()->route('users')
                    ->with('success','User Role Updated Successfully');
}
```

The error is on the `foreach` in the controller

> ErrorException:
>   Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Since I'm sure that I pass correct `user_id` and correct value of `role_id` why is this error?

```
dd($request->input('roles'));
```

return correct id which I'm choose on checkbox.

Comment: Why are you using PATCH in update method ? and `$request->input('roles')` not seems to be array so the error is encountered.

Comment: `$request->input('roles')` can you show the vardump of this ?

Comment: I'm using PATCH because if I try with PUT or POST got methodnotallowed error

Comment: @kasper this is the var_dump `string(1) "7"`

Comment: @Peter can you add output of `dd($request->input('roles'));` ?

Comment: @SagarGautam the result is `"7"`

Comment: It means you didn't get roles as array so simply directly assign that role without loop

Comment: @Peter looks like you have single role for a user in your system, so there is no need to use foreach loop, just update the role of the user at once.

Comment: Without foreach is working when I try to assign one role, yes.

Comment: @Peter Do you have multiple roles for the user ?

Comment: If you want to have multiple roles for the system, look at the answer of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the existing role and attach the new one like this:

```
DB::table('role_user')->where('user_id',$id)->delete();
$user->attachRole($request->input('roles'));
```

I think you have single role in the `role_user` table for each user, so you can use find and update method as well.

Like,

```
DB::table('role_user')
   ->where('user_id',$id)
   ->update(['role' => $request->input('roles')]);
```

This way will reduce extra overhead of unnecessary delete and with just single query you can update role of the user.

I hope you have understood.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like it because of the direct update in DB query.

Comment: @Peter and no need to delete this reduce extra overhead :D

Answer (score 1):

You are getting role as string not as array so directly assign it without loop

```
DB::table('role_user')->where('user_id',$id)->delete();
$value = $request->input('roles');
$user->attachRole($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `roles` is an array. Then use

```
foreach ($request->input('roles') as $value)
{
    $user->attachRole($value);
}
```

The reason is you have only a single value to the id, not an associative array. So you are trying to use invalid parameter for `foreach`

If your `roles` is not an array make it an one.

This method allows use to keep more than 1 role.

For example to make your `$request->input('roles')` an array 
try with

```
if(!is_array($input->request('roles')))
    $roles[] = $input->request('roles');
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer but I still get the same error.

Comment: can you please elaborate the nature of `roles`

Comment: OK @Peter i updated the answer, Your `$request->input('roles')` is not an array. Please make sure it is an array

Answer (score 0):

The reason you had that error because in your view you have defined the roles as a single valued input. You need to add `[]` to the name of your input.

```
{{ Form::checkbox('roles[]', $value->id, in_array($value->id, $userRole) ? true : false, array('class' => 'name')) }}
```

Then you can access `roles` like an array in your controller. But you need to check for the existence of `roles` or pass a default value as it is not sent to the server if every checkbox is unchecked.

```
 foreach ($request->input('roles', []) as $role) {
      $user->attachRole($role)
 }
```

Or you can leverage Eloquent and define a `roles` relationship in your `user` model.

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('roles');
}
```

and in your controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'roles' => 'required'
    ]);

    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->update($request->all());

    $user->roles()->sync($request->input('roles', []));

    return redirect()->route('users')
                    ->with('success','User Role Updated Successfully');
}
```